# Testing a service that depends on $state

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

I've been trying to write a unit test for my *Progress Service*, which manages the different states of a flow (jumps to next incomplete step, marks step as complete, etc.)

I'm trying to configure $stateProvider to create a set of states and then test the service against it, but I can't get the state to change. Of course I would like to test this in an isolated way, so not depending on existing states in my application.

Here's the simple unit test:

```
ddescribe('Progress Steps Service', function() {

    var sut, $rootScope, $state;

    // holds ui.router and ProgressStepsService deps
    beforeEach(module('Core'));

    beforeEach(inject(
        function(_$rootScope_, _$state_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $state = _$state_;
        }
    ));

    beforeEach(inject(function(ProgressStepsService) {
        // var steps = [...];
        // sut = ProgressStepsService;
        // sut.resolve(steps);

        angular.module('TestModule', []).config(function($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('root', {url: '/root', abstract: true})
                .state('root.step1', {url: '/step1'})
                .state('root.step2', {url: '/step2'})
                .state('root.step3', {url: '/step3'});
        });

        $state.go('root.step1');
        $rootScope.digest();
    }));

    it('should init from the first step', function() {
        expect($state.$current.name).toBe('root.step1');
    });
});
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Error: Could not resolve 'root.step1' from state ''
```

I take `''` is the default state, and for some reason the configured states are not navigable. I'm probably missing something very basic.

How should I configure the `$stateProvider` to test against arbitrary states?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here it is what I think was happening:

I was loading `$state` before configuring it via `$stateProvider`, and in addition, I was not injecting the TestModule.

I've updated the code to look like this:

```
ddescribe('Progress Steps Service', function() {
    var sut, $state, $rootScope;

    beforeEach(function() {
        // var steps = [...];
        // sut = ProgressStepsService;
        // sut.resolve(steps);

        angular.module('TestModule', []).config(function($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('root', {url: '/root', abstract: true})
                .state('root.step1', {url: '/step1'})
                .state('root.step2', {url: '/step2'})
                .state('root.step3', {url: '/step3'});
        });

        module('Core', 'TestModule');
        inject(function(){});
    });

    beforeEach(inject(
        function(_$state_, _$rootScope_) {
            $state = _$state_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        }
    ));

    it('should transition to the first incomplete state', function() {
        $state.go('root.step1');
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect($state.$current.name).toBe('root.step1');
    });
});
```

which does the trick.